# Variation of Bazanski Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, geodesics

The Bazanski Lagrangian is defined as

$$
L=g_{\alpha \beta }U^{\alpha }\frac{D\psi ^{\beta }}{Ds}
$$

and

$$
U^{\alpha }=\frac{\mathrm{d} x^{\alpha }}{\mathrm{d} s}
$$

$x^{\alpha }$ is the Particle coordinates and $s$ is the proper time. $\psi ^{ \beta }$ is the $s$-dependent deviation vector associated with one parameter family of geodesics $X^{\alpha }(s,\epsilon )$ according to 
$$
\psi ^{\beta }=\epsilon \left |\frac{\partial X^{\beta }}{\partial \epsilon }  \right |_{\epsilon =0}
$$
the deviation vector is defined as the displacement of two objects travelling along two infinitesimally separated geodesics

I am unable to calculate the variation for this lagrangian. if i define an infinitesimal parameter $\epsilon $ such that

$$
\psi ^{\beta }(s,\epsilon )=\psi ^{\beta }(0,\epsilon )+\epsilon \delta \psi ^{\beta }
$$

I can use that to substitute for 
$$
\frac{\partial \psi ^{\beta }}{\partial \epsilon }=\delta \psi ^{\beta }
$$
but what's the relation between $\frac{\partial X ^{\alpha }}{\partial \epsilon }$
and $\delta \psi ^{\beta }$ so I can be able to find the Euler-Lagrange equation for this vector

Comment: This reads as quite confusing because you don't exhibit any definition of $\psi$ and because you seem to be using $X$ twice - once for position, and once for geodesics. Please add a definition of $\psi$ - only then can one decide whether it changes the coordinates $X$ at all.

Comment: i edited the post and added the definition of the deviation vector.

Comment: What about just using the Euler-Lagrange equations for $\psi$ doesn't work here? I.e. why do you think it works any different here than for any other Lagrangian?

Comment: the problem is that i don't just want to use the Euler Lagrange equation, i want to derive the formula for this vector and then will be using the definition of D/DS operator to find the geodesic equation. calculating the action for any Lagrangian as $L(x,y(x),y'(x)), y'=\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}$ so there has to be some kind of connection between y and y'. when i try to vary L with respect to $\psi $just as any lagrangian i get stuck at the point where i need to find a relation between $\delta \psi ^{\beta } and X^{\beta }$